# Styled components - why is animation not working?

Tags: css, animation, styled-components, ticker

We failed at getting this example to work using styled components in react.

Why is the animation not working in our code? I cannot get it to move and had to resort back to using normal css for success. Must be a simple mistake somewhere

```
import React from 'react'
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'
import './ticker.css'





export default function Ticker({ text }) {
      return (<div class="ticker-wrap">
        <div class="ticker">
          <div class="ticker__item">Letterpress chambray brunch.</div>
          <div class="ticker__item">Vice mlkshk crucifix beard chillwave meditation hoodie asymmetrical Helvetica.</div>
          <div class="ticker__item">Ugh PBR&B kale chips Echo Park.</div>
          <div class="ticker__item">Gluten-free mumblecore chambray mixtape food truck. </div>
        </div>
      </div>)
    }


 @-webkit-keyframes ticker {
     0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    }
     100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @keyframes ticker {
     0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    }
     100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}
 .ticker-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: #FDFCF8;
  padding-left: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.ticker-wrap .ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: ticker;
  animation-name: ticker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-duration: 30s;
}
```

Comment: This is the example we tried to rework into working with styled components https://codepen.io/lewismcarey/pen/GJZVoG

Comment: Welcome to SO! As i can see you missed the styles of inner item form above mention example, please double check the styles